# How to change ButtonField text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="CareerFormID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="CareerFormID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CareerFormID")%>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Checked" DataField="checked" />

<asp:ButtonField Text="Edit" CommandName="Select" ButtonType="Link" />

    protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idtemp = (GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("CareerFormID") as Label).Text;
    Session["CompanyFormID"] = idtemp;
    Response.Redirect("Management_Edit.aspx");
    //Response.Write(Session["CompanyFormID"]);
}
```

I want to change ButtonField text="Modify" when DataField="checked" is 1, How can I do this?

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "1")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Yes";
            e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Modify";

        }
        else if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "0")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "No";
            e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

    }

}
```

But this don't work, the cells[6] text is changed but the link is cancel.

For Example like that, the link can not working when I change the text

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7ugk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Makes event handler when DataField="checked" is 1 (I don't find it in your code, how to make it to 1) and do this

```
//begin of event handler
//check datafield="checked" is 1, I still don't get it this one
 ButtonField.Text="Modify"
//end of event handler
```